# Serializing interface in wcf

Tags: .net, wcf, interface

I designed an application that has an interface and two inherited classes:

```
interface IPerson {}
class Man:IPerson{}
class Woman:IPerson{}
```

Now, I wrote a method that looks like this:

```
public IPerson GetPeron(int idNumber);
```

This method gets an ID number and looks for that number in the DB. If that number belogns to a man, a new Man instance is created, data from the DB is being put into the new instance and finally the instance returns. The same goes if the given ID belongs to a woman

Now I want that method to be placed not on the client side but on a WCF server. The problem is that the return type can't be an Interface anymore.

The obvious solution is to create three methods:

A. Get an ID and return an enum that represent the person type:

```
enum PersonType { Man,Woman }
PersonType GetType(int personID);
```

B. Gets an ID and return a Man:

```
Man GetMan(int personID);
```

C. Gets an ID and return a Woman:

```
Woman GetWoman(int personID);
```

I think that's kind a lousy, any better suggestion?

Comment: You should try generics, somenting like public T GetPerson(int id) where T is IPerson and Iserializable

Answer (score 1):

If it really is as simple as this example (no multiple implementation or other base classes involved), a base class instead of (or in addition to) an interface would work:

```cs
public interface IPerson { }

[KnownType(typeof(Man))]
[KnownType(typeof(Woman))]
public class BasePerson : IPerson { }

public class Man : BasePerson { }
public class Woman : BasePerson { }

[OperationContract]
BasePerson GetPerson(int value);
```

Your proxy will generate the base class and the concrete  classes, so when you call:

```
var x = proxy.GetPerson(3);
```

`x` will be declared as type `BasePerson`, but the actual type of the object will be either `Man` or `Woman`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly when working with WCF you cannot have interfaces, abstract base classes or classes without the default (empty) constructor. That bothered me a lot, but you have to choose between WCF and good OO practices...

The best I came to was to create auxiliary *wcf-interfaceable* concrete classes to use on WCF contracts and the operators I needed to implicit convert between their instances and the corresponding *business* classes.